# How do I tell yay not to show diffs, permanently?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, software-updates

When I run `yay` to upgrade packages I see the following:

```
 Diffs to show?
==> [N]one [A]ll [Ab]ort [I]nstalled [No]tInstalled or (1 2 3, 1-3, ^4)
```

I'd like to permanently answer 'N' ('None') to this question. How can I do that, so I that I don't get prompted every time?

Note, I don't want to add these args in an alias because I will lose the ability to invoke yay with no args.

Comment: examine the command line options

Comment: @jsotola This doesn't quite answer the question. I'd like to set this permanently. If I alias `yay` to `yay --answerdiff None` then this changes the behaviour of `yay` when invoked with noargs.

Comment: it was not an answer ... only a suggestion about where to start looking ... you could create an alias ... or a bash script that checks arguments

Comment: Fair enough. `yay` is resistant to aliasing to add arguments, because it has special behaviour when no arguments are provided.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've found I can permanently answer yay questions like this:

```
yay --save --answerdiff None --answerclean None --removemake
```

The `--save` option creates a file at ~/.config/yay/config.json with these settings set for future runs of yay.